# 'UIImagePickerController' and 'allowsEditing' hide those lines on editing view

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I assure that UIImagePickerController always returns a squared image? WhatsApp does it but I have not found a way to achieve this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CVln.jpg[image]

its done by just using ImagepickerView and allowing editing

my code :-

```
   // setting profile pic

    let myImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myImagePickerController.delegate = self
    myImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
  // myImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera



    myImagePickerController.allowsEditing = true


    self.presentViewController(myImagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i just want the same editor but without those lines , is there's any possible way for achieving this ?

P.S.  this question is already being asked but haven't answer yet thats why am asking it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better you should use an custom view and post your selected image from segue and and there use one of this libraries https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper  and sorry for answering this should be an comment but have no reputation for that :/